# Delete boost file?

Tags: caching

Is there a way to delete a file of the boost cache? On my site users can submit content and i need that only the previous node of the currently created node to be deleted(flushed). When I flush all my pages after creating a node my site gets slow. So i wonder if this could be made.

Comment: can you elaborate this "i need that only the previous node of the currently created node to be deleted(flushed)"?

Comment: Did you mean "I need to flush previous version of edited content from Boost cache immediately after edit"? Boost flushes cache of a given node on it's edit. Not flawlessly, but it does just that. So either you encountered a bug in Boost (not impossible, as managing cache is complicated task), or we need to know more about your setup to help.

Comment: I'm having a site where anonymous users can upload a link of an image and a title of the image. Then from the link and title through my custom module is created a node. I'm having a lot of users who are uploading it and creating nodes. From that goes that the boost flush is frequently executed and all my cached files are flushed. For better performance it would be better to just delete the previous node couse my nodes are linked with next and previous links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the [Cache Expiration](https://www.drupal.org/project/expire) module:

This will delete the exact files that were impacted by the content edit.